# Evaluating an XPath expression in XML

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When using the Add-on SDK to create a Firefox add-on, how do you process an XML file?
Evaluate with XPath throws an error:

> XPathResult is not defined

I am trying to process [this XML data](http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/?filter=live&xml=1) with this code:

```js
var iterator = xmlDoc.evaluate('//stream', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a lot of global classes available in the window context aren't there in SDK modules which are sandboxes. You can access this constant via [`nsIDOMXPathResult` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMXPathResult):

```js
var {Ci} = require("chrome");
var iterator = xmlDoc.evaluate('//stream', xmlDoc, null,
    Ci.nsIDOMXPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
```