# XPathEvaluator in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xpath

I am attempting to follow [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath) to evaluate an XPath expression. My code is copy/pasted from the article:

```
// Evaluate an XPath expression aExpression against a given DOM node
// or Document object (aNode), returning the results as an array
// thanks wanderingstan at morethanwarm dot mail dot com for the
// initial work.
function evaluateXPath(aNode, aExpr) {
  var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
  var nsResolver = xpe.createNSResolver(aNode.ownerDocument == null ?
    aNode.documentElement : aNode.ownerDocument.documentElement);
  var result = xpe.evaluate(aExpr, aNode, nsResolver, 0, null);
  var found = [];
  var res;
  while (res = result.iterateNext())
    found.push(res);
  return found;
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Message: ReferenceError: XPathEvaluator is not defined

Is Mozilla's article out of date, perhaps? Is there a more up-to-date article available on parsing XML in an SDK add-on?

Edit. When I tried it this way:

```
var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var domXPathEvaluator = Cc["@mozilla.org/dom/xpath-evaluator;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMXPathEvaluator);
```

I got a long error message:

```
- message = Component returned failure code: 0x80570019 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_CREATE_WN) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
- fileName = undefined
- lineNumber = 14
- stack = @undefined:14:undefined|@resource://helloworld-addon/index.js:14:25|run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:145:19|startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:86:7|Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:920:23|this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:799:7|this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:738:39|Promise*this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:738:7|this.PromiseWalker.schedulePromise@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:762:7|this.PromiseWalker.completePromise@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:705:7|handler@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/window.js:56:3|
- toString = function () /* use strict */ toString
```

edit 2. Here, I'll just post my whole code, because it's clear something stranger than I thought is going on. I've created a hello-world addon using the Mozilla tutorials including [this one to display a popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup). I've modified that further so that it will append text to a file, and modified that further to, I hope, parse and modify XML.  So the resulting add-on is supposed to take text entered in the popup and append it to an XML file.

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var text_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
        contentURL: data.url("text-entry.html"),
        contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
    });

const fooFile = "/Users/sabrina/Documents/addon/foo.xml";

var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var parser = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/domparser;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMParser);
//var domXPathEvaluator = Cc["@mozilla.org/dom/xpath-evaluator;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMXPathEvaluator);
var foo = parser.parseFromString(readTextFromFile(fooFile), "application/xml");

// Create a button
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
        id: "show-panel",
            label: "Show Panel",
            icon: {
            "16": "./icon-16.png",
                "32": "./icon-32.png",
                "64": "./icon-64.png"
                },
            onClick: handleClick
            });

// Show the panel when the user clicks the button.
function handleClick(state) {
    text_entry.show();
}

text_entry.on("show", function() {
        text_entry.port.emit("show");
    });

text_entry.port.on("text-entered", function (text) {
        console.log(text);
        //      appendTextToFile(text, "/Users/sabrina/Documents/addon/output.txt");
        appendFoo(text);
        text_entry.hide();
    });

function appendFoo(text) {
    var newNode = foo.createElement("blah");
    newNode.innerHTML = text;
    var mainFoo = evaluateXPath(foo, '/foo')[0];
    mainFoo.appendChild(newNode);
    foo.save(fooFile);
}

function evaluateXPath(aNode, aExpr) {
    var xpe = new XPathEvaluator();
    var nsResolver = xpe.createNSResolver(aNode.ownerDocument == null ?
                                          aNode.documentElement : aNode.ownerDocument.documentElement);
    //var result = domXPathEvaluator.evaluate(aExpr, aNode, null,
    //                                      domXPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    var found = [];
    var res;
    while (res = result.iterateNext())
        found.push(res);
    return found;
}

function readTextFromFile(filename) {
    var fileIO = require("sdk/io/file");
    var text = null;
    if (fileIO.exists(filename)) {
        var TextReader = fileIO.open(filename, "r");
        if (!TextReader.closed) {
            text = TextReader.read();
            TextReader.close();
        }
    }
    console.log(arguments.callee.name + ": have read " + text + " from " + filename);
    return text;
}

function writeTextToFile(text, filename) {
    var fileIO = require("sdk/io/file");
    var TextWriter = fileIO.open(filename, "w");
    if (!TextWriter.closed) {
        TextWriter.write(text + "\n");
        console.log(arguments.callee.name + ": have written " + text + " to " + filename);
        TextWriter.close();
    }

function appendTextToFile(text, filename) {
    var textplus = readTextFromFile(filename) + text;
    writeTextToFile(textplus, filename);
}
```

I run at the command line using `jpm run` which opens Firefox Developer Edition. I click the addon button, the popup comes up, I enter text, I hit return, and I see this in the console:

```
JPM undefined Starting jpm run on Sabrina's Helloworld Addon
Creating XPI
JPM undefined XPI created at /var/folders/gg/r_hp4hzs0gdfy70f__l18fmr0000gn/T/@helloworld-addon-0.0.1.xpi (46ms)
Created XPI at /var/folders/gg/r_hp4hzs0gdfy70f__l18fmr0000gn/T/@helloworld-addon-0.0.1.xpi
JPM undefined Creating a new profile
console.log: helloworld-addon: readTextFromFile: have read <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo><blah>eek</blah><foo>
 from /Users/sabrina/Documents/addon/foo.xml
console.log: helloworld-addon: ook
console.error: helloworld-addon:
JPM undefined   Message: ReferenceError: XPathEvaluator is not defined
  Stack:
    evaluateXPath@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://helloworld-addon/index.js:63:9
appendFoo@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://helloworld-addon/index.js:57:19
@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://helloworld-addon/index.js:50:2
emitOnObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:112:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:89:38
portEmit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/sandbox.js:343:7
emitOnObject@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:112:9
emit@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/event/core.js:89:38
onContentEvent/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/content/sandbox.js:384:5
delay/<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/lang/functional/concurrent.js:38:20
notify@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/timers.js:40:9
```

Comment: You should really show your code.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the code that is causing the error. It is literally copy/pasted from Mozilla's article.

Comment: This runs fine even in the js scratchpad (shift + f4). And obviously, you wouldn't be running a very old version of firefox. What does the console say if you paste the code in the js scratchpad, add `console.log(evaluateXPath(document.body, '//img'));` after it, and run it on this question's page ?

Comment: I'm using the Firefox Developer Edition 41.0a2, and this is the response I get:
/*
Exception: ReferenceError: evaluateXPath is not defined
@Scratchpad/1:10:1
*/

Comment: when I follow your request properly (oops) this is the response I get: 
[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement],[object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that I am running Firefox Developer Edition by invoking `jpm run`. Is it possible that something environmentally is being left out that way?

Comment: I wouldn't know offhand but it is a venue to explore. What was different when the code failed compared to the success case ?

Comment: Rather than try to summarize, I've just posted my whole addon.

Comment: The following link suggests a sdk sanboxing issue. If it is actually relevant, using `Cc` is the way to go, even though it currently fails in a different way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10522459/3512867 This might also be of interest: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2854793 I'm left to wonder if this can be done using the SDK.

Comment: Thank you @spenibus! That speaks directly to my problem. If the SDK is broken for client-side XML parsing because of sandboxing and bugs, how would you recommend I make my addon? Just write in regular javascript and bundle the XPI manually?

Comment: I've always done my addons using the overlay method and self packaging, so I might be a bit biased. Start here and see what works for you: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/

Comment: If you have a DOM Node then you can simply use `node.ownerDocument.evaluate(xpath, node, null, someXPathResultType, null)` as any DOM document implements the `evaluate` method respectively the XPathEvaluator interface. Why do you need to create an XPathEvaluator?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I was working through Mozilla's tutorials. The building consensus here seems to be that what I'm trying to do won't work and I'm basically forced to do it that way (straight-up javascript).

Comment: Martin's proposal would presumably allow you to keep using the sdk, it might be worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Non-authoritative, speculative answer

In a different question, [Wladimir Palant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785541/wladimir-palant) (author of Adblock Plus, presumably he has good knowledge of firefox) said:

> Yes, a lot of global classes available in the window context aren't there in SDK modules which are sandboxes.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10522459/3512867

This could explain why `XPathEvaluator` is not defined in the SDK addon.

The logical conclusion would be to use Firefox's `Components` object to access the `nsIDOMXPathEvaluator` interface. Which brings up the following error:

> NS_ERROR_XPC_CANT_CREATE_WN

Looking into it takes us to this, from mozillazine's forums user "lithopsian":

> That means it can't create a wrapper for a non-javascript interface.

Source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2854793

I am unable to judge the credibility of that statement and while the linked bug reports seem to be relevant, I can not attest they actually are:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=994964
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027095
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1029104

Unless those informations are confirmed (or dispelled) by people with a deeper knowledge of Firefox's internal workings, I can only hesitantly conclude that the  `nsIDOMXPathEvaluator` interface can simply not work in an SDK addon.